# Passing UN and PW through a HTTP response

Tags: asp.net, redirect, response, credentials

I was wondering if its possible to redirect a user to a web page that required a username and password such as the one you would require for an IIS authenticated web site and automatically send through the UN and PW, eg -

```
Response.Username = "";

Response.Password  = "";

Response.Redirect("url");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible under any of the authentication forms provided by default. This would not work across domains either.